# Set checked property of all check boxes depending on a condition without "for" or "while" loops, a jquery callback is accepted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array say

```
var arr = [true, false, false, true];
```

and I have four check boxes with same class

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" class="someclasss">
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" class="someclasss">
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" class="someclasss">
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" class="someclasss">
```

Is it possible to set the checked property of these check boxes using jquery/ javascript without without "for" or "while" loops, a jquery callback is accepted.

Comment: why wont you loop when you need to loop?

Comment: So `$('#c1').prop('checked', arr[0]);` for each one changing the number each time.

Comment: Actually I have lot of check boxes, just asking is it possible ??

Comment: Why would you not want to loop? It's like asking how can I cross the Atlantic without flying? Sure it's possible, but you're discounting the easiest and quickest method.

Comment: @Deckerz not exactly

Comment: It literally doesnt make sense, not wanting to loop

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how is it possible ??

Comment: @Subhasis its not possible unless you know the exact amount of checkboxes each time in which case my code works.

Comment: See @guradios answer. But be aware that it's not very robust code. If you add or remove an element from the array your code won't work and will need maintenance

Comment: If you have _any_ action that needs to be performed multiple times - then asking how to do this without loops is about the most nonsensical question one could possibly ask.

Comment: You will have to loop as soon as it comes to an unknown amount of checkboxes (which I assume your question is including). At least at some point or implicit (e.g. jQuery loops through the elements if you do a kinda $('.someclasss').anyMethodChangingAnItem() anyway)

Comment: check the answer, you will know.

Comment: Which answer should we check? The one you accepted features a loop,just because it's a loop that jQuery hides from you doesn't negate that simple fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use call back function, while assigning checked property for check box.

Try this below code.

```js
var arr = [true, false, false, true];
$(".someclasss").prop("checked", function(index) {
  return arr[index];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" class="someclasss">
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" class="someclasss">
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" class="someclasss">
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" class="someclasss">
```

Comment: And how is that not a loop, the only difference is that jQuery is doing the work internally.

Answer (score 1):

Looping would be best. But here is small working code for you:

```js
var arr = [true, false, false, true];
$.each(arr,function(key,val) {
  $(".someclasss").eq(key).prop("checked", val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" class="someclasss">
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" class="someclasss">
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" class="someclasss">
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" class="someclasss">
```

Comment: Then I could have written it this way

$(".someclasss").each(function(idx) {
  this.prop("checked", arr[idx]);
});

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [true, false, false, true];

$(".someclasss").eq(0).prop('checked',arr[0])
$(".someclasss").eq(1).prop('checked',arr[1])
$(".someclasss").eq(2).prop('checked',arr[2])
$(".someclasss").eq(3).prop('checked',arr[3])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" class="someclasss">
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" class="someclasss">
<input type="checkbox" id="c3" class="someclasss">
<input type="checkbox" id="c4" class="someclasss">
```

1. Use index

Answer (score 0):

You can only make them all the same without looping, not a mixture of properties.

```
$(".someclasss").prop("checked", false);
```

By why would you want to do that?

Comment: Well, he doesn't want to make them all the same.

Comment: thats the only way to do it without looping.. otherwise you need to do them 1 by 1, so why not just put the checked property on to the html?